# Changing VisualState of a control by binding it with some property of ViewModel

Tags: wpf, expression-blend, viewmodel, visualstatemanager

Considering the code below:

```
 xmlns:interactivity="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity"

...

 <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsGlobalControllerAttached}" Command="{Binding Path=AttachDetachGlobalControllerAction}" ToolTip="{Binding Path=GlobalControllerToolTip}" Visibility="{Binding Path=CanApplyDateFilter, Converter={StaticResource bool2VisibilityConverter}}" Style="{StaticResource toolBarToggleButton}">
                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <ei:DataStateBehavior Binding="{Binding IsGlobalControllerCreated}" Value="true" TrueState="Normal" FalseState="Disabled" />
                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <Image Source="../../Common/Images/pin.png"/>
            </ToggleButton>
```

I am trying to set VisualState of Toggle Button by binding it to some property in ViewModel.
Here, I am not able to find the Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.dll in the "Add Reference" list. I am using VS 2010. 
What am i missing? Do i need to install Expression blend to get this dll?

Also,
Is there any other way to get the job done? ( Changing VisualState of a control by biding it with some property of ViewModel).

Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use Attached Properties to manage custom state changes on elements. These are then just bound to the view model.

e.g. for a "split screen" setting we do the following.

**Create a DependancyProperty in a class called SplitScreen, with a property called Mode:**

```
    public class SplitScreen
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ModeProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Mode",
                                        typeof(SplitScreenMode),
                                        typeof(UserControl),
                                        new PropertyMetadata(SplitScreenMode.None,
                                            new PropertyChangedCallback(OnScreenModeChanged)));

        public static void SetMode(DependencyObject obj, SplitScreenMode value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(ModeProperty, value);
        }

        public static SplitScreenMode GetMode(Control obj)
        {
            return (SplitScreenMode)obj.GetValue(ModeProperty);
        }

        static void OnScreenModeChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            var control = sender as UserControl;
            if (control != null)
            {
                if (control.Parent == null)
                {
                    control.Loaded += (s, e) =>
                                          {
                                              ApplyCurrentState(control);
                                          };
                }
                else
                {
                    ApplyCurrentState(control);
                }
            }
        }
        [snip]
    }
```

You might note our little trick to *late-update* the value when Attached Property is initially set (there is often no parent element until the page is fully loaded).

**In the Xaml file attach the property to the required element like this:**

```
lib:SplitScreen.Mode="{Binding SplitScreenMode}"
```

The key is to catch dependency property changes and get that to change the visual state of the attached element (this is the snipped part of the SplitScreen.cs file):

```
static public void ApplyCurrentState(Control control)
{
    string targetState;
    switch (GetMode(control))
    {
        case SplitScreenMode.Single:
            targetState = SplitScreenModeName.Single;
            break;
        case SplitScreenMode.Dual:
            targetState = SplitScreenModeName.Dual;
            break;
        default:
            targetState = SplitScreenModeName.None;
            break;
    }
    VisualStateManager.GoToState(control, targetState, true);
}
```

**The alternative is to install the Expression Blend SDK**
You do not need Expression Blend to make use of the SDK and all the cool extras. It is a lot less work for simple items (we just needed some custom behaviour it did not support).

Comment: Can someone point to some info about how to do so on Blend ??